# What does "expert insight" mean?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the combination of "expert" and "insight" as one word in "expert insight". I know that expert is an adjective and insight is a noun described by it, but what does this combination mean in whole? Does it refer to a person that has a good knowledge in a perticular field of study or it means something else? Thanks.

Comment: You should include the context where you came across the term.

Comment: It's a title on a programming book and doesn't exist in a context.

Comment: If you google the string "expert insight" (with the double inverted commas) I can  guarantee you'll get some examples with context. In fact, [OpenPR.com](https://www.openpr.com/wiki/expert-insight) offers loose definitions. Apparently wisely as there seems to be no precise definition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Edwin, but don't you have any idea about the meaning?

Comment: Looks like the title of a series, implying that studying the books will give you more than  basic insight and turn the reader into an expert.

Comment: Surely 'expert insight' is the type or degree of insight that would be expected from an expert?

Comment: @Michael Harvey That comment might pass muster now this question is on ELL. From the brief look I had at the string, it looks weasel-wordy. Who defines 'expert'? I assume that 'insight' is the non-count usage.

Comment: I think you're right Yosef, thanks for your offer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - seems to be a term bandied about a lot by public-relations and marketing people.

Comment: The mistake is assuming that it's an Adjective-Noun phrase. It's not. It's a Noun Compound, with two nouns making one idea, like _pony ride_ and _snake bite_. In this case the noun _expert_ means a human who is an expert in something (given the context, probly coding), and _expert insights_ means the insights an expert might have (which you're sposta understand is what makes them an expert, so you can be too if you read the book).